# Firebase - Set Firebase references dynamically based on user input

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to set firebase references dynamically. What I know from the doc is firebase set references at the initial state. As long as I try to make it dinamic it give me permission error.

For example I want to get fruit name from the input, so the code:

```
$('.fruit').click(function(){
    var name = $(this).text();
    getFuitName(name);
});

function getFruitName(name){
    var fruit = firebase.database().ref('fruit/' + name );
    fruit.once('value', function(snapshot) {
        console.log(snapshot.val().name);
    });
}
```

What should I do? Any special approach to do this?

Comment: Include your firebase database screenshot. Also try to console snapshot.val() first.

Comment: call  **getFruitName(name)** instead of  **getFuitName(name)** ,  see the missing **r**

Answer (score -2):

I found the solution. I've to separated the database references like this:

```
var database = firebase.database(); // I add this line

$('.fruit').click(function(){
    var name = $(this).text();
    getFuitName(name);
});

function getFruitName(name){
    var fruit = database.ref('fruit/' + name ); //and then modified this line
    fruit.once('value', function(snapshot) {
        console.log(snapshot.val().name);
    });
}
```

Comment: This does not even change your code. There clearly was another issue. But great if it works now.

Comment: This does not make any sense